# Full calendar sheduler with an extra long resource

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm having trouble showing a vertical scheduler.

this is what i'm using:

```
$('#timetable').fullCalendar({
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        editable: true,
        resourceAreaWidth: "100px",
        defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
        slotLabelFormat: ['MMMM','D'],
        eventAllow: function(dropLocation, draggedEvent) {
            var originalEvent = $('#timetable').fullCalendar('clientEvents', draggedEvent.id)[0]
            return dropLocation.start.isSame(originalEvent.start) && dropLocation.end.isSame(originalEvent.end)
        },
        header: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineWeek,timelineMonth,agendaToDisplayFourWeek'
        },
        views: {
            agendaToDisplayFourWeek: {
                type: 'timeline',
                slotDuration: {hours: 12}, 
                duration: { month: 3 }
            },
            timelineMonth: {
                eventOverlap: false,
                slotDuration: {hours: 24},
                slotLabelInterval: {days: 1},
                type: 'timeline',

            },
            timelineYear: {
                eventOverlap: false,
                slotDuration: {hours: 1},
                slotLabelInterval: {days: 1},
            },

        },
        resources: [
        { id: 'a',  title: 'Bahamas' },
        { id: 'b',  title: 'Longbeach' },
        { id: 'c',  title: 'Mentawai' },
        { id: 'd',  title: 'Wau' },
        { id: 'e',  title: 'Sin asignar' },
        { id: 'e1',  title: 'Sin asignar' }
        ],
        events: [
        { id: '1', resourceId: 'e', start: '2018-07-01', end: '2018-07-10', title: 'event 1' },
        { id: '6', resourceId: 'e', start: '2018-07-01', end: '2018-07-10', title: 'event a' },
        { id: '2', resourceId: 'e', start: '2018-07-01', end: '2018-07-10', title: 'event 2' },
        { id: '3', resourceId: 'e', start: '2018-07-01', end: '2018-07-10', title: 'event 3' },
        { id: '4', resourceId: 'e', start: '2018-07-01', end: '2018-07-10', title: 'event 4' },
        { id: '5', resourceId: 'e', start: '2018-07-01', end: '2018-07-10', title: 'event 5' }
        ]
    });
```

this produces the next result:
https://codepen.io/monxas/pen/VdRwwM?editors=0010

as you can see there's some unintended behavior at the bottom part.

Comment: "as you can see there's some unintended behavior"...no, it all seems to be correct. Can you explain what you consider to be the problem, precisely?

Comment: @ADyson below the "Sin asignar", which is the last resource it draws a long (in height) empty row. https://imgur.com/a/VjtSSJZ

Comment: It's not a bug, it's just because the calendar has a certain height by default, determined partly as a ratio of its width. You can control it to a certain extent using these settings: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing . The calendar is a grid onto which the resources and events are overlaid as a second layer of content. Therefore what you're seeing is not an empty row, it's merely the _absence_ of resource rows. You can make the default height smaller if you prefer. Of course if you make it too small, or the height of the resource rows grows due to events, the user will have to scroll.

Comment: thanks @ADyson , I got it working

Comment: Providing `height: "auto"` seems to solve your problem.